# How to show the marker points in line graph using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, data-visualization, linegraph

I am using `Line graph` in my application and is working fine. I tried to draw the marker points in line graph,but the marker points are not displaying.
In line chart marker properties, I have chosen `markerSize` as 5,`markerStyle` as Circle,`MarkerColor` as blue.Refer my code below.

```
 series1.Name = "Series1";
 series1.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
 series1.IsXValueIndexed = true;
 series1.XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
 series1.YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
 series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
 this.chart1.Series.Add(series1);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't see how the `Markers` can show up from your code.

You need to set a **non-default** [`MarkerStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.markerstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
 series1.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
```

If you use the **debugger** on that line you can see how the **default** is `None` !

Of course you will want to play with all other [marker relates series properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which all inherited from the [DataPointCustomProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcustomproperties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You are using `ChartType.Line` which is fine. Note that `FastLine` does not display markers!

If you only want to show some Markers simply style them for each point:

```
S1.Points[8].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Triangle;
S1.Points[8].MarkerSize = 22;
S1.Points[8].MarkerColor = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest getting each of your points, looping through them and adding each one. I noticed you want to set a name so I just created a counter then appended an integer value to the end of 'ser', name how you please.

```
Dim counter as int = 0;
foreach (Series ser in chart.Series)
{
   ser.Name = "ser" & counter + 1;
   ser.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
   ser.IsXValueIndexed = true;
   ser.XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
   ser.YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
   ser.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
   this.chart1.Series.Add(ser);
   counter += 1;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I need is I want to add marker points(dots) to the line chart while plotting itself to the respective values.